# Open terminal and run command, from the command line

Tags: command-line, bash, gnome-terminal, gnome-shell

I am looking for a way to launch a terminal session from the command line on Ubuntu, something like this:

```
#/usr/bin/env bash

terminal -c 'node server.js'
```

if there is some cross-platform tool that also works on MacOS that'd be nice.

So I tried this:

```
gnome-terminal -- 'echo "foo" | bash'
```

and I got this:

[image]

And when I try this:

```
gnome-terminal --tab -- echo 'ts-node /home/oleg/codes/typeaware/doc-gen/lang/typescript/api/src/.test/express.test.ts' | bash
```

nothing happens, the gnome-terminal never opens.

Comment: The correct command would be `gnome-terminal -- sh -c 'echo "foo"; bash'` or `gnome-terminal -- bash -c 'echo "foo"; bash'`

Answer (score 9):

Your initial command, `gnome-terminal -- 'echo "foo" | bash'`, attempts to run a program named literally `echo␣"foo"␣|␣bash`, which you most likely don't have on your system.

The correct syntax would be `gnome-terminal -- sh -c 'echo "foo" | bash'`, but it would not help, unless you actually have an executable named `foo`. You can see that the syntax is correct by trying

```
gnome-terminal -- sh -c 'echo "date; sleep 2" | bash'
```

But this is just a very complicated way of saying

```
gnome-terminal -- bash -c 'date; sleep 2'
```

As for the intended command, it probably should be

```
gnome-terminal --tab -- bash -c 'ts-node /home/oleg/codes/typeaware/doc-gen/lang/typescript/api/src/.test/express.test.ts'
```

Comment: thanks, yeah these work well, one problem remaining is when I use ctrl-c the terminal window closes, I want to keep it open and drop into the shell after killing the process originally run. I tried a few things like `gnome-terminal -- bash -c 'cmd && bash'` but doesn't always work.

Comment: I am also looking to add the command to the bash history. I can add it to the bash history with `history -s 'cmd'` but it's not showing up in the history when I hit the up arrow when using the history -s command in my gnome-terminal command.

Comment: This will trap the SIGINT, but it fails to add the command to bash history `gnome-terminal -- bash -c 'history -s cmd; trap bash SIGINT; cmd;`